# Cardinality of the set of all bit strings not containing the bit "0" (i.e. $11$, $111$ ...)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I need to show the cardinality of $S$, the set of all bit strings that don't contain the bit $0$.

I came up with a function that maps $\mathbb{N}$ to $S$ in the following way:

$f(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 10^i$.

I think that this is a valid mapping because each natural number $n$ gets mapped to the string that contains exactly $n$ bits.

**My question:** I am having trouble understanding if this function is bijective.

My attempt:

**Injectivity:** Well, I'd need to prove that for $f(a) = f(b) \implies a=b$

$$f(a) = \sum_{i=0}^{a-1} 10^i = .f(b) = \sum_{i=0}^{b-1} 10^i$$

$10^0 + 10^1 + ...+ 10^{a-1} = 10^0 + 10^1 + ... + 10^{b-1}$

I'm stuck here. I don't know if I can cancel out all terms except the $10^{a-1}$ and $10^{b-1}$ (mostly because I can't operate on the presumption that $a=b$, that's what I need to prove).

**Surjectivity**: I don't know how to prove this mathematically.

Can anyone help?

Comment: How exactly do you define strings? Because technically speaking, $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 10^i$ is **not** a string, it is a number!

Comment: @5xum That's my mistake, I meant "string" as an n-tuple of ones. I wonder if my approach can still somehow be used?

Comment: Well if $f(a)$ is an $a$-tuple of ones, and $f(b)$ is a $b$-tuple of ones, and $f(a)=f(b)$ then clearly, $a=b$, because two tuples can only be equal if their lengths are equal.

Comment: Also, surjectivity is more or less obvious, but if you really want to, it can simply be proven by induction.

Comment: @5xum Thank you very much. I forgot to think in terms of tuples.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're mixing up several different concepts. The term "string" refers to digits being considered just a collection of *symbols*. That is, the "string" 11 refers to two instances of the 49th ASCII character. This is different from 11 being considered as a base ten number, in which it is equal to $2 \times 2 \times 2+2+1$. This is in turn different from it considered as a base two number, in which it is equal to $2+1$.

Now, as for proving that $f(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}10^i$ is injective, it's clearly strictly increasing, because $f(n+1)-f(n)= 10^n>0$. And strictly increasing functions are injective. The geometric series formula gives you that $f(n) = \frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$. In this case, $r=10$, so that is  $\frac{10^n-1}{9}$. $10^n$ is $1$ followed by $n$ zeroes. $10^n-1$ is $n$ nines.  $\frac{10^n-1}{9}$ is $n$ ones. So it's possible to get $n$ ones for any $n>0$.

You can also use the geometric series to prove injectivity; if $a \neq b$, then WLOG, $a <b$, so $f(a) = \frac{10^a-1}{9} < \frac{10^b-1}{9}$.

Answer (score -1):

Every positive integer $n$ corresponds $1-1$ with the string $1\cdots 1$ with $n$ ones , so the cardinality is the same as the cadinality of the positive integers , hence $\aleph_0$ , the strings form an infinite countable set.

Comment: well that's essentially what I wanted to prove (which is something I knew intuitively), I even constructed a function that maps the natural number $n$ to its corresponding string.

Do I actually need to mathematically prove this is a bijection?

Comment: I think $colon > hyphen > dash$ when it comes to represent the word "to" in "one to one".

Answer (score -1):

In fact since $10^i>0$ you can prove strict monotonicity ($a<b\implies f(a)<f(b)$) quite easily hence injectivity.

For surjectivity finding the inverse function directly is also not too complicated.

i.e. $x=34$ then $4=10\times\{\frac x{10}\}$ and $3=(x-4)/10\quad$  (note: $\{x\}$ designate the fractional part)

This can be extended to decompose a number into its digits $d_i$ as below:

$\begin{cases}d_0=0\\x_0=x\end{cases}\ $ and $\ \begin{cases}d_{i+1}=10\times\{\frac {x_i}{10}\}\\x_{i+1}=(x_i-d_{i+1})/10\end{cases}$

Therefore as in our case all digits are either $1$ or trailing zeroes then $n=\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty d_i$

Answer (score -1):

One way to prove that function $f$ defined by
$$f(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 10^i$$
is a bijection is to guess its inverse function, and prove that that is indeed its inverse function.

Let $g$ be the function defined by
$$g(N) = \log_{10}(9N+1).$$

For instance $g(1111) = \log_{10}(9\times1111+1) = \log_{10}(10000) = 4$.

Now all you have to do is prove that for every nonnegative integer $n$, $g(f(n)) = n$, and for every number $N$ which is a string of 1, $f(g(N)) = N$.

Comment: ah ah nice abuse of the most significant digit.